# ARIMA model for GDP

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, state-space-models, dlm

I am working through example 3.2.6 in 'Dynamic linear models with R' by Petris. I have download the quarterly deseasonalised USA GDP data located here: http://definetti.uark.edu/dlm/ (it's the data set called gdp5004.dat)

Before leaping into representing this as a DLM, I am trying to create an ARIMA model. I thought I understood the steps to do this, but it's a tad confusing.

It says there is a trend component + output gap. The literature suggests the output gap can be described by an AR(2) model.

The questions I have are:

- how is it known the output gap can be described as an AR(2) model?
- There are 5 unknown parameters in the DLM (see section 6 in the code below - buildGap). The way the DLM is constructed suggests to me the series needs to be differenced twice (because dW=exp(u[1:2]) and that there are 2 AR components (because ar=u[4:5]). The remaining unknown is from sigma2=exp(u[3]). This suggests to me the data fits an ARIMA(2,2,0) model - is this right?
- why when I fit an ARIMA model to the data do I get ARIMA(1,1,0)? I obtained this result by analysing the ACF and the PACF. I also checked the output using auto.arima and got the same result (see my code below steps 1-5). Is this right? It conflicts with the bullet point above, no?

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
library(fpp)
library(forecast)
library(dlm)

# 1. read in data from Petris' website
gdp_ <-read.table("gdp5004.dat", header=TRUE)
gdp<- ts(gdp_, frequency = 4, start =1950)
log_gdp<-log(gdp)

#2. plot log of time series
plot(log_gdp, xlab = '', ylab = 'log US GDP', type = 'l')

#3. take difference to make the series stationary
plot(diff(log_gdp), type='l')

#4. check the acf and pacf of differenced series
#   because the PACF has a significant spike at lag 1, set p=1
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
Acf(diff(log_gdp), main='ACF- difference')           
Pacf(diff(log_gdp), main= 'PACF - difference')    
dev.off()

# analysis of acf/ pacf and taking differences suggests an ARIMA(1,1,0) model is appropriate 

#5. try auto.arima() - this yields ARIMA(1,1,0)
fit<-auto.arima(log_gdp, seasonal = FALSE)
fit
accuracy(fit)
acf(residuals(fit), main = 'ACF residuals - ARIMA(1,1,0)')  


#6. compute the MLE of the unknown parameters
level0<-log_gdp[1]
level0
slope0<-mean(diff(log_gdp))
slope0

buildGap<- function(u){
  trend <- dlmModPoly(dV = 1e-7, dW= exp(u[1:2]), m0=c(level0, slope0), C0=2*diag(2))
  gap   <- dlmModARMA(ar=u[4:5], sigma2=exp(u[3]))
  return<- (trend+gap)
}

init<-c(-3,-1,-3,.4,.4)
outMLE<-dlmMLE(log_gdp, init, buildGap)
outMLE$value
dlmGap<-buildGap(outMLE$par)
sqrt(diag(W(dlmGap))[1:3])
GG(dlmGap)[3:4,3]
```

Comment: Why dont you start with straight arima on log GDP? For instance arima(1,1,0)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment Aksakal